# How to set the action of a NSButton in a binding scenario?

Tags: cocoa, binding, nsbutton, nscollectionview

I have a button that is inside a view repeated inside a NSCollectionView. I can bind the title of the button to one of the properties in my model class but I want to wire the selector of the button to one of the selectors in my model class. Obviously, the button must send the message to the model object associated with the corresponding collection view item.
I managed to bind the target for the button but how to set the selector? I want to do that in Interface Builder if possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In the Ib there is a selector textbox bellow the path textbox where I bind the target. I don't know why I didn't see it. I spent nearly one hour trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

How to add those blindings? I still can't find it.

[image: see?]

I find it . It's Here.

[image]